# Apply transformations on a RDD column while selecting other columns in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I want to be able to select multiple columns of a RDD while applying transformations to one of the values. I am able to
- select specific columns
- apply transformations on one of the columns

I am unable to apply both of them together

1) Selecting specific columns

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
logFile = "/FileStore/tables/tendulkar.csv"  
rdd = sc.textFile(logFile)
rdd.map(lambda line: (line.split(",")[0],line.split(",")[1],line.split(",") 
[2])).take(4)

[('Runs', 'Mins', 'BF'),
('15', '28', '24'),
('DNB', '-', '-'),
('59', '254', '172')]
```

2) Apply transformations to the 1st column

```
df=(rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(",")[0])
  .filter(lambda x: x !="DNB")
  .filter(lambda x: x!= "TDNB")
  .filter(lambda x: x!="absent")
  .map(lambda x: x.replace("*","")))
df.take(4)

['Runs', '15', '59', '8']
```

I tried to do them together as follows

```
rdd.map(lambda line: ( (line.split(",")[0]).filter(lambda 
x:x!="DNB"),line.split(",")[1],line.split(",")[2])).count()
```

I get an error

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2766458519992264> in <module>()
     10       .map(lambda x: x.replace("*","")))
     11 
---> 12 rdd.map(lambda line: ( (line.split(",")[0]).filter(lambda x:x!="DNB"),line.split(",")[1],line.split(",")[2])).count()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in count(self)
   1067         3
   1068         """
-> 1069         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
   1070 
   1071     def stats(self):
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply the filter with the first element in each row after your map where you select all columns you wanted:

```py
rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(",")[:3]) \
   .filter(lambda x: x[0] not in ["DNB", "TDNB", "absent"])
```

Comment: One quick question. I need to apply the transformation of replacing "*" with "", and when I do this , I am back to square one again of having only the first column 
                                                                                                         
                     rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(",")[:3]) \
   .filter(lambda x: x[0] not in ["DNB", "TDNB", "absent"]).map(lambda x:x[0].replace("*","")).take(3)

Comment: You need to select other columns in the last `map`. `.map(lambda x: [x[0].replace("","")] + x[1:])`

Comment: -Thanks. That works. I need to think through the syntaxes(?) you include!